# Unable to find explicit activity class. Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, activity

Манифест:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.comp.physics.FavoritesActivity"
        android:label="@string/favorites_title">
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.comp.physics;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FavoritesActivity.class); // <-----
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

FavoritesActivity.java:

```
package com.example.comp.physics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FavoritesActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку получаю ошибку:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.example.comp.physics/com.example.comp.physics.FavoritesActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Что я упустил?

Comment: мне кажется, вам нужно сделать ребилд проекта

Comment: @metalurgus, большое спасибо, нужно было действительно просто пересобрать проект!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Попробуйте отнаследовать вторую активити также от AppCompatActivity вместо просто Activity.
2. Ещё вариант - прописать в манифесте не всё имя, а сокращенное, как и в случае первой активити:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".FavoritesActivity"
       android:label="@string/favorites_title">
   </activity>
   ```
3. Также, возможно, дело в `instantRun` функции студии - попробуйте отключить её в настройках.